# ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype float32

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

**ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("embedding_1/random_uniform:0", shape=(4518, 1), dtype=float32)'**

```
File "C:\PythonProjects\combined\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1050, in convert_to_tensor as_ref=False):

@tf_export("convert_to_tensor")
def convert_to_tensor(value, dtype=None, name=None, preferred_dtype=None):

File "C:\PythonProjects\combined\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1146, in internal_convert_to_tensor
ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)

internal_convert_to_tensor(value=value,dtype=dtype,name=name,preferred_dtype=preferred_dtype,as_ref=False)
```

My question is how to change dtype into int32?

Answer (score 0):

you can cast a tensor from float32 to int32 either using `tf.cast(given_tensor, tf.int32)` or `tf.to_int32(given_tensor)`.